# Extracting data from a XML file via a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-intelligence

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that extracts records from a XML file and inserts them into a table.

The issue is that some records in the XML contain the field 'Receipt Amount' and some records have 'Payment Amount'.

These fields are the same thing just named differently.

On the table the field is called 'Receipt amount'.

My question: is there a way to insert records into the 'Receipt amount' column in the table without amending the XML file?

Both are money fields.

Can the stored procedure be amended to cater for both without adding another field to the table?

Comment: With enough time and effort, probably.  What have you tried so far and what was the result of that attempt?

Comment: Depending hows your procedure extracting these values you could use exist() function, or coalesce combined with value() function...update the question with the procedure which you already have

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer requires that you [give us some more details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4137916) in the form of code, not prose.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Thanks guys

Comment: Jared.. could you please share your answer so that others might find it useful...